# tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath doesn't work correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a really strange problem.
I have a `UITableView` in a view controller, I can customize all that I want it works. But I want that when I click on a row an other view appear (it is not difficult), so I have done that:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath");
    self.myFicheView.hidden=NO;

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

But when I click on a row the method is not called. Like it doesn't work I have tried many things and I have found something strange.
When I click briefly on the row nothing happen, but when I click during 3 seconds it work and when I slide my finger on the row too.

Somebody know what is the problem here ?

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
{

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
```

here the connections inspector of my tableView
http://hpics.li/256d01e

Comment: Have you added self.myTableView.delegate = self; ?

Comment: @iPatel that will not change anything in this case, it is ok for the property to retain it. strong, weak or retain.

Comment: Make sure the tableView can respond to selection by setting [tableView setAllowsSelection:YES];

Comment: I guess you're not setting the delegate properly.. If you are setting the delegate via Xib, you need to connect the delegate and datasource to your file owner..

Comment: If it was a delegate problem then he wouldn't have said `"when i click during 3 seconds it work"`

Comment: Can you try by removing `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];`?

Comment: Check your files owner of your viewController. As your image says, MapViewController should be your files owner.

Comment: you want that i remove that in the didSelectAtIndex method ? Because i already do this.

Comment: Why do you have `deselect table` at the bottom? Please try removing that.

Comment: Where is self.myFicheView placed - is it a subview of main view? Is it in front of the table view?

Answer (score 2):

I exactly have no idea how your xib looks like, assuming if the view is coming somewhere in front of your table view, try to bring your tableview in front to that unhidden view.

Assuming if you have put `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];` method only to unhide the selection then there is a property in xib which provides you this facility, by using this you can remove this method and try to run your code. Please give a snapshot of your xib or some of your implemented code for better clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will not call the delegate method

plz include this code to your viewDidLoad method

```
myTableView.delegate=self;
myTableView.dataSource=self;
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Like i have say, it work , but not corectly. I must click 3 seconds for call the method didSelectRowAtIndex.

Comment: Please see the question properly. Connections have already been made in the StoryBoard.

Comment: you just ensure that didSelectRowAtIndexPath you are calling....before i had made a mistake I called the didDeselectRowAtIndexPath method..plz ensure that also

Comment: It is the good method. I think it is not a question of wrong method, but setting. In fact it work, but not normally.I just want that when i click just one time on the row it work.